# Getting ID of Selenium WebElement in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

If I have the following HTML `<a id="id" class="class" href="href">Element Text</a>` how would I get "id" to be returned? My current procedure is:

```
print("Attribute: " + element.get_attribute('id'))
print("Property: " + element.get_property('id'))
print("Class: " + element.get_attribute('class'))
```

But all of those return empty strings. I am, however, able to get the text by using `element.text`

EDIT: Here's a more in depth explanation

I'm looking for an element but that element's ID varies. There is, however, an element linked to the element I want that I can find using it's xpath and comparing it's text to a specific text that I know beforehand. The ID of that element is something in the form of someID_XX. By taking the XX and appending it to another fixed string, I can then search for the element that I actually want. My issue is that once I get the second element (not the one I want directly, but the one that can lead me to the one I want) I can't seem to get it's ID attribute even though it seems to have one in the html. My question is, how do I get the id attribute?

Comment: Did you try :`driver.find_element_by_id('id')`

Comment: I have the element already, found using xpath. Now I need the id of the element.

Comment: What selector did you use to locate element?

Comment: xpath: //*[@id="id"]. The issue is that the actual id is "id_XX" where XX is a varying number. I find this element by searching for a string and then I need the XX to find another element which uses XX in it's ID

Comment: If `id` looks actually like `"id_XX" ` then you cannot fetch it with `//*[@id="id"]`. If you successfully can locate element by `@id` then you should get its value with `get_attribute('id')`... Can you share some more code?

Comment: the "id" was just a placeholder to make the question simpler to understand. There is a specific element that I want but it has a varying ID so I can't search for it directly. The only way I can search for it is by looking for another element that has very specific text. Once I find that element (I find it using that element's xpath) I was hoping to get it's ID using get_attribute("id") which I could then use to find the element that I actually want. I've update the OP to explain this process a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

For me is working with

```
element.get_attribute('id')
```

At the beginning didn't work because I selected incorrectly a hidden javascript element without id.
But if the error persist on your case, you can try this:

```
element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

get the DOM for the element, and then parse the html to extract the id